# Failed to fetch at tesseract.min.js:1 at Worker.e.onmessage (tesseract.min.js:1) -- tesseract issue

Tags: cordova, ocr, tesseract, worker

I'm working on tesseract recognition and try to read language from Folder locally in cordova project , when I put the language path on server it works , but when the path is locally in www Folder give me error , can anyone help me what's the correct way to set language path in Cordova project ?

I use tesseract "version":"2.1.4"
the Error :
[tesseract.min.js:1 Uncaught Error: TypeError: Failed to fetch at tesseract.min.js:1 at
Worker.e.onmessage (tesseract.min.js:1)][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZiCk.png

---

```
  const worker = Tesseract.createWorker({
    workerPath: 'js/worker.min.js',
    corePath: 'js/tesseract-core.wasm.js',
    langPath: 'lang-data/',
    logger: m => console.log(m)
    });
    Tesseract.setLogging(true);
    work();
    async function work() {
    await worker.load();
    await worker.loadLanguage('tha');
    await worker.initialize('tha');
    result = await worker.recognize('https://tesseract.projectnaptha.com/img/eng_bw.png');
    console.log(result.data);
    await worker.terminate();
    }
```